# template for groupRowInnerRenderer ag-grid version 1.14.1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am currently using ag-grid to render the group and I used the version 1.14.1. This ag-grid is used the groupRowInnerRenderer to render group. See the image below:

[image]

and I am looking for the default template of groupRowInnerRenderer so I can add the button "Get Default Configuration" to only group name = Space but I couldn't find the code for groupRowInnerRenderer. 
Can you please direct me where to find the template for groupRowInnerRenderer of ag-grid version 1.14.1
Thanks